# Maximum area of a rectangular field that can be fenced and divided in half by a fence

Tags: calculus, optimization

A rectangular pasture is to be fenced then divided in half by a fence parallel to 2 opposite sides. If a total of 6000m of fencing is used, what is the maximum area that can be fenced?

I have no idea where to begin with answering this question.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Also, you should at least complete the last sentence.

Comment: Regarding where to begin... let $x$ and $y$ be the lengths of the sides. Then you want to maximimise $A=xy$ subject to the constraint that $ax + by - 6000 = 0$, where we are adding up the amount of fencing. If we define $x \leq y$, then $a = ?$ and $b = ??$...

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but with this one, I need more guidance.

Comment: step 1: draw a diagram

Comment: Did that, am stumped on what principles I am supposed to be using here. Further assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> *What is the **maximum** area that can be fenced ?*

**Hint**: The maxima and the minima are to be found amongst the roots of the function's first order derivative. So, what is your function, which needs to be maximized ? $xy=\max$, correct ? But we also have $2~(x+y)+y=6000\iff$ $y=2000-\dfrac23x$. Now, replace *y* with its expression in *x* in the first equation, compute its derivative, and find its roots. Can you take it from here ? :-)